# Add element to array and generate Hash with two arrays in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Need to add two arrays before that need to add some value at starting of the first array. Look at the following:

```
@conunty_format = [ "country", "imps", "revenue","network_revenue"]
final_ca = [2000,55.62,88.69]
```

I need to add "Canada" to final_ca and generate hash with corresponding county_format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Array Zip and some properties of Array to achieve it in a single line. see the below code.

```
resulted_hash = @country_format.zip(final_ca.unshift("Canada")).inject({}) do |r, s|   r.merge!({s[0] => s[1]}) end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Hash[@conunty_format.zip(final_ca.unshift('canada'))]

=> {"country"=>"canada", "imps"=>2000, "revenue"=>55.62, "network_revenue"=>88.69}
```